# Using new File in laravel 5.3 return an empty object

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.3 in my app and in the docs ,I found that

```
Storage::putFile('photos', new File('/path/to/photo'));
```

in Filesystem

Then I tried it but it gave an error.

new `File()` always return an empty instance of `Illuminate\Support\Facades\File`
and it ignores the construct param

So why I can't use it? or is this is a bug?

By the way is,`$request->file('object')` instead would be ok?

Comment: Which error did you get? Do the server have write access to the storage folder?

Comment: It reported hashName() get an null parameter ,If I tried $file = $request->file('object') which return an instance of Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile then it works